# Recording (contact) forces in meshcat

Tags: drake

I am running a simulation in pydrake where I give a disturbance to my robot in the form of an externally applied spatial force. My goal is visualize and record this disturbance as well as the contact forces drawn by ContactVisualizer in meshcat. However currently the recording only shows the arrows as they were at the last time step of the simulation. If I understand the documentation correctly only published events get recorded, but my attempts at declaring a publish period for my LeafSystem have not yielded the desired results. So my question is: How do I change the behavior of my LeafSystem and the ContactVisualizer to record all the intermediate states of these arrows and display them in the meshcat recording?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation with the meshcat recording at the moment. I started typing a long response here, but decided to open an [issue on Drake](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/17832) with the detailed answer so that we can track the resolution.